# get username by NT id

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server where NT id's are stored - NT000002, NT0000003, etc.

I would like to get the actual username using the above id. How do I do that?

Comment: is it real `NT` userid

Comment: [Querying Active Directory through SQL Server](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Insights/Skyline-Blog/May-2013/Querying-Active-Directory-through-SQL-Server-Using)

Comment: @lad2025 it's showing to get user by username but I don't have that. I only have NTXXXXXX and I need to get the actual username.

Comment: @darkpool how you get this id's `NT000002,...`

Comment: If the `NT Id` is an Active Directory SID, you can use the `SUSER_SNAME` function, e.g. `SELECT USER_SNAME(@SID)`

Comment: @tinka it was in a table, instead of actual username that table has those NT ids.

Comment: @darkpool it's mean you don't know how this id comes in table because it seems this id is not a original id if you want to get all NT Users even all users then you can run this query  `SELECT *
FROM sys.server_principals `

Answer (score 0):

Check the below queries, is this what you want ?
Query 1 -

```
Select p.loginame,p.nt_domain,p.hostname,p.nt_username
from master.dbo.sysprocesses p (nolock)
```

Query 2-

```
Select d.name,p.hostname,p.nt_username,p.loginame,p.nt_domain
from master.dbo.sysprocesses p (nolock)
join master..sysdatabases d (nolock) on p.dbid = d.dbid
and d.name <> 'master' and d.name <> 'msdb'
```

Comment: It gave me users on SQL server. But users I'm talking about are Windows users. Do I need to query ActiveDirectory then?

Comment: I guess so, if the user information are stored in AD then u need to create a  linked server to Active Directory interface and then query LDAP.